# Is it possible to have default values for properties in an interface while still maintaining their type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

about TypeScript default params
code:

```
interface Options {
    name: string,
    age: number,
    salary?: number
}
function printEmployee(employee: Options = { name: 'John Doe', age: 30, salary: 5000 })  {
    console.log(`Name: ${employee.name}, Age: ${employee.age}, Salary: ${employee.salary}`);
    console.log(employee.salary.toFixed())
}

printEmployee(); // Name: John Doe, Age: 30, Salary: 5000

printEmployee({ name: 'John Doe', age: 35 }); // Name: Jane Doe, Age: 35, Salary: 5000
```

why employee.salary maybe 'number | undefined'，it has default value.

employee.salary is number

Comment: Nothing stops you from calling `printEmployee({ name: "a", age: 1 })` and then `employee.salary` does *not* have a default value.  Perhaps you wanted something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3v9qN) instead where you allow a `Partial<Options>`.  Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
interface Options {
    name: string,
    age: number,
    salary?: number
}
function printEmployee(employee: Options = { name: 'John Doe', age: 30, salary: 200})  {
    console.log(`Name: ${employee.name}, Age: ${employee.age}, Salary: ${employee.salary}`);
    if(employee.salary)
    {
        console.log(employee.salary.toFixed()) // its a number 
    }
    console.log(employee.salary?.toFixed()) // if it's a number
}
printEmployee(); // Name: John Doe, Age: 30, Salary: 5000

printEmployee({ name: 'John Doe', age: 35 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is correct; you have supplied a [default argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) to `printEmployee()`, but this is only used if someone calls `printEmployee()` with no arguments.  It does not do anything if someone passes in an actual `Options` argument, and `salary` is [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) in `Options`, and therefore possibly undefined.  Indeed, your own example doesn't actually behave the way you say it does.  What you actually get looks like this:

```
printEmployee({ name: 'Jane Doe', age: 35 }); // no compiler error, but
// RUNTIME ERROR!  employee.salary is undefined
```

There's a runtime error that `employee.salary` is undefined, which is exactly what the compiler is warning you about.

---

If you wanted the `salary` property of the argument to have a default, you might have used [a default destructuring assignment value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#default_value) instead, like this:

```
function printEmployee({ name, age, salary = 5000 }: Options = 
  { name: "John Doe", age: 30 }) {
  console.log(`Name: ${name}, Age: ${age}, Salary: ${salary}`);
  console.log(salary.toFixed())
}

printEmployee(); // Name: John Doe, Age: 30, Salary: 5000    
printEmployee({ name: 'Jane Doe', age: 35 }); // Name: Jane Doe, Age: 35, Salary: 5000
```

Of course this also destructures the properties into separate variables instead of keeping them in an `employee` variable.  If you need that then you might give up on having the default be part of the parameter and just [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) the parameter into a new variable with the requisite default:

```
function printEmployee(_employee: Options = { name: "John Doe", age: 30 }) {
  const employee: Required<Options> = { salary: 5000, ..._employee };
  console.log(`Name: ${employee.name}, Age: ${employee.age}, Salary: ${employee.salary}`);
  console.log(employee.salary.toFixed())
}

printEmployee(); // Name: John Doe, Age: 30, Salary: 5000    
printEmployee({ name: 'Jane Doe', age: 35 }); // Name: Jane Doe, Age: 35, Salary: 5000
```

Or some other approach might fit your use case better.  The main point is that default arguments do not merge with actual arguments; they are simply ignored.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkgJbAAuEATgGYLIDyMZxA9sFHoUUqJAFxIoZSqQDmAGi5EQoiAOABXMACMqk7oMwhKATwD88paspcAvvi69ocREnojRnKUmoLg8ZmyQwR5AKJgMBgsOhAQABQQgcGhcnZMrOxIALx4POBxAOQoLAAWwEgAIiwQmeJIMnEAzAAM5VBaugIArDVtSKYAlJwaRPBsUCwYEAB0waLhAAYAchkCACS4UUEhYSNWpuUAgrILS9Gro5WbSADKjTp7yzFrDRjaOqaTnQDczn0DQ6PjkQexI3cHiMyCwAGLEAAeEAAJuFOp1nOYNMIdD1ej5SGQAitYuFcOl+EhsnkCsVSuVKgIqs0Oq9EUh0GR4LkkJFugRegzPsMxiwJhBugB6QVIABKAFVpgAVACSAFk-Eg-KLRfRReVrocARcSBw3NCINRSDCAISIiwaDH+P5hOEvJDCpCzQk5fJFErbXZIWrlc73JpIVptC0dENWWB0JDgiEARicGlc7k8BStWJtEXxVgpsnqOtSQZqHQEjGTHFSmbmSAARK7SSUq9nqoWumiNP12F9eRMZpXFhtPXFFsdfRc9oDdE86Zz24MeT9xzpgWDITC4QiNOZnKnsTcIq8HSLnXFa+6IAOqXUzqPA21C9wt740zjbRXCdkQMBkGSyhUvdTafajpHgIKAfl+HpIDs1TNCO-qXDewZEJuRDhjYyDRgATPG3CJh4iTeI+O6HOEAD6mqxMWCQDCkaRWAINYkqeDa-k2tKttwM5kEg5FhAIooQAAjgoxCUDCAA8JaJFAAB8NH4guLS3uUIwqWR6YdG807ct8fJTMBSCLDxoz9pBXqGemIzDlecFXBZC6TppvQzp2PxGdqcFLtGq7wuaD6YkRuL7kBlYnmS57epefoPIp7T3pahHpniBJZKBn6nj+lLejSXSAYeIVgae4XUrB0UITUZgWKYQA)